# External library installation in eclipse without maven

Tags: android

I want to use this library in my project:https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

But I am not using gradle or maven,I am using eclipse.

What should i do for install this library to my project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below step

****Download Zip code form github -> extract and go to circularimageview-eclipse -> import project CircularImageView parrlle to you project -> after import completion right click on your CircularImageView -> go to propeties -> android and select checkbox isLibrary**

**Now right click on your project -> propeties -> android -> add library -> choose CircularImageView from popup -> apply -> OK****

Now you are able to use this library in your project.